# iPhone app crashing with objc_msgSend when combining pushViewController and presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Here's the scenario:
On my iPhone app (OS 3.1.2), I've got "view 1" which navigates to "view 2" using a pushViewController call. Then, on "view 2", the user can optionally call "view 3", which is displayed using presentModalViewController and an animation (flip horizontal transition).
I can switch view 1 <-> view 2 back and forth without any problem.
But if I do view 1 -> view 2 -> view 3, I can get back to view 2 (with the appropriate dismissModalViewControllerAnimated call in view 3) ; once in view 2, getting back to view 1 makes the application crash with the "standard" objc_msgSend error.

Here's how I navigate from view 1 to view 2:

```
NewsArticleController *articleViewController = [[NewsArticleController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsView" bundle:nil news:f1Data];
articleViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:articleViewController animated:YES];
[articleViewController release];
```

Here's how I navigate from view 2 to view 3:

```
addFeedController = [[AddFeedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddFeedView" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addFeedController];
[addFeedController release];
navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
[navigationController release];
```

Here's how view 3 dismisses to get back to view 2:

```
- (IBAction)cancel
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And finally, the stack trace:

```
#0  0x96a8aedb in objc_msgSend
#1  0x04859550 in ??
#2  0x01c26908 in CFRelease
#3  0x01c49869 in __CFDictionaryDeallocate
#4  0x01c26a41 in _CFRelease
#5  0x00043cf5 in NSPopAutoreleasePool
#6  0x035f7858 in run_animation_callbacks
#7  0x035f75f5 in CA::timer_callback
#8  0x01c67ac0 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific
#9  0x01c66c48 in CFRunLoopRunInMode
#10 0x0245378d in GSEventRunModal
#11 0x02453852 in GSEventRun
#12 0x002d3003 in UIApplicationMain
#13 0x000023b0 in main at main.m:5
```

Maybe I'm blind and don't see the error here, but I'm really stuck. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 2nd block of code I posted, I was doing:

```
addFeedController = [[AddFeedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddFeedView" bundle:nil];
...
```

As you might infer, addFeedController was defined as an instance variable. Of course, I was nicely releasing that variable in my dealloc. But actually, I just can't remember why I ever needed this variable to be put in the instance. This precisely caused that variable to be released twice if ever allocated once.
A local variable with a local release was enough and this stopped my app from crashing.

NSZombie helped me catch this bug... Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is fine.

The problem occurs because an object is getting prematurely deallocated.  It's probably related to some code in your 3rd view.

You can use [NSZombie](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingAutorelease) to help you find the problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to zombieland! By using this technique I managed to find out that stupid bug.
FYI, you can see in the 2nd block of code I posted that I was doing "addFeedController = ...", meaning that variable was defined as an instance variable.
Of course, I was releasing that variable in my dealloc. But actually, I just can't remember why I ever needed this variable to be put in the instance. A local variable with a local release was enough and this stopped my app from crashing.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

For your `-cancel` action method, shouldn't that be:

```
[[self navigationController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: When doing this, the code compiles and runs fine, but the "Cancel" button doesn't do anything anymore (nothing is dismissed). It must be something else, but thanks anyway.

Comment: That's odd. Perhaps look into NSZombie to see if you have overreleased or released an object early.

Answer (score 0):

When navigating from view 2 to view 3, your creating a new UIViewController. I cant really see why you'd do this.
To navigate to view 3, you could just do:

```
addFeedController = [[AddFeedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddFeedView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:addFeedController animated:YES];
[addFeedController release];
```

Comment: You're right, thanks, I changed my code in that way.
It doesn't keep my app from crashing however, so this isn't the reason.